# simplify react function to get current user

Tags: reactjs

I am writing a function that using an ajax call to hit an API endpoint to get current user, it could be anonymous user or a actual one. the `initial` variable is set to true if it's used in constructor, false if it's used elsewhere. Don't know if this is the right way to do, or if the code is clean, for example: Is using initial to switch setState and this.state assignment the right way to do in react?

```
loadCurrentUser(initial = false) {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'accounts/api/users/current',
}).done((responseData) => {
  const data = responseData.data;
  const isAuthenticated = data.is_authenticated;
  let stateData;
  if (isAuthenticated) {
    stateData = {
      displayName: data.display_name,
      reputationPoint: data.reputation_point,
    };
  } else {
    stateData = {
      displayName: null,
      reputationPoint: null,
    };
  }

  if (initial) {
    this.state = stateData;
  } else {
    this.setState(stateData);
  }
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be simplified to this:

```
state = {displayName: null, reputationPoint: null}

componentWillMount() {
  this.loadCurrentUser()
}

loadCurrentUser() {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: '/accounts/api/users/current',
}).done(responseData => {
  const {is_authenticated, display_name, reputation_point} = responseData.data;
  if (is_authenticated) {
    this.setState({
      displayName: display_name,
      reputationPoint: reputation_point,
    });
   }
});
}
```

Mainly it's always a good idea to set the initial value in constructor level, let it be empty/null values. Then you can call `setState` from anywhere as necessary. Otherwise as the async AJAX request might get delyed, anywhere you reference the `this.state.displayName` or anything, will generate error.

Comment: Thanks for answer my question! Do you mind telling me what's the different between calling the loadCurrentUser in the componentWillMount and in the constructor?

Comment: Just deferring the call. By the time it get's called in `componentWillMount`, all of the props and initial states would have been set. Otherwise i's almost same.